# What is the difference between Algebraic extension and Algebraic closure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Algebraic extension says every element of extension field E of field F is algebraic over F. But that's also the definition of Algebraic closure. I'm confused. Please explain the difference.

Comment: The algebraic closure can be thought of as "the biggest possible algebraic extension".

Comment: What did you not understand in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure ?

Comment: It's not also the definition of algebraic closure. This is the same as the difference between a bag of apples, and a bag of all of the apples in existence.

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at an example to see the difference.

Let $F=\mathbb{Q}$ and consider the extension field $E=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})=\{a+b\sqrt{2}\mid a,b\in\mathbb{Q}\}.$  Then any element $a+b\sqrt{2}\in E$ satisfies the polynomial $f(x)=x^2-2ax+a^2-2b^2\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$, and hence we see that $E$ is algebraic over $F$.

An algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is an algebraic extension $E$ of $\mathbb Q$ such that every polynomial in $E[x]$ has a root in $E$.  Consider the polynomial $x^2-3$.  This polynomial has no root in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ (you can check this using the standard form of an element in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ as above).  It follows that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ cannot be an algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Note that up to (noncanonical) isomorphism, algebraic closures are unique, so we often refer to *the* algebraic closure of $F$.

Comment: "An algebraic closure of Q is a field E such that every polynomial in Q[x] has a root in E. " I don't think that would be sufficient. Every polynomial in E[x] should have a root in E! Thus the field E admits not algebraic extensions.

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I've edited my response.

Comment: This is very old but seems to have popped up, so to stick my nose in a little bit: even the current definition is not quite right, it needs to also state that $E$ is algebraic over the ground field ($\mathbb Q$). For instance, without this $\mathbb C$ would count as $\bar{\mathbb Q}$. Also, it does in fact suffice for each polynomial from the ground field to have a root in $E$; of course this requires proof.